# Is it possbile to publish one SNS Topic to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a requirement where my application, in AWS account A, needs to broadcast that a new resource is created, to AWS accounts: B, C and D.

I was thinking of implementing a solution, where an SNS Topic in Account A, publishes to SQS Queues Accounts: B, C and D (FanOut Pattern).

Question: Is it possible to use SNS Topics in account B, C and D rather than SQS Queues?
Basically, is it possible to subscribe one SNS Topic to another?

I was not able to find anything that concretely answered the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Amazon SNS is not an available subscription type.

[image: SNS Subscription types]

You could subscribe an AWS Lambda function and that Lambda function could send messages to desired SNS topics.